# Approximating Log(Gamma(z)) for small z as Log(Gamma(z + 1)) - Log(z)

Tags: numerical-methods, gamma-function, approximation-theory

I'd like to implement a numerical approximation to the log Gamma function, and I found Gergő Nemes' approximation described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation.

This seems to work great when $z$ is big, but not so well for small $z$.

The docs for [Boost's lgamma function](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/special/sf_gamma/lgamma.html) suggest a funny trick though: just do `LogGammaApprox(z + 1) - Log(z)`. And indeed, that does seem to work well for small $z$ with the Nemes approximation.

I have a naive question then: what are the downsides to just always using that trick? It'll obviously be less efficient for larger $z$ where the original approximation was already good, but is it expected to be less accurate as well?

Comment: Roughly how small are we talking about for the "small" case? The first thing you would want to check for is whether there is risk of subtractive cancellation. A not uncommon way to approximate $\log (\Gamma (x))$, for $x$ in, say, $[0,0.5]$, is to compute $- \log (p(x))$, where $p(x)$ is a polynomial minimax approximation to $1 / \Gamma(x)$.